# Selenium IDE If-Else logic problem

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a problem with Selenium IDE If-Else processing. My script is ignoring the logic and running both the If and the Else.

I want the script to check whether I have a single item or a group in my cart. If I have a single item, I want to do the single item delete, and if I have a group, I want to do the group delete.

If I have a single item, my script is doing the single item delete, then it goes on to do the group delete and fails the test with an element not found error.

The code of my if-else is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!-- ${Deletes} is set earlier -->
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${Deletes}==true</td>
    <td>Stepssingle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${Deletes}==false</td>
    <td>Stepsgroup</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>Stepssingle</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Delete</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Delete Value: ${Deletes}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>link=Delete</td>
    <td>Deletes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>End</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>Stepsgroup</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=a.button.delete-share</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[2]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Delete Value: ${Delete}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=a.button.delete-share</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>link=Delete</td>
    <td>Deletes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>End</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have reworded your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two major potential problems here.

First: You don't have if-else logic. You have two consecutive if statements which will be run one after the other.

Second: Your second if statement is run after the value of your `Deletes` variable is changed from `true` to `false`.

From what I saw in a quick websearch your if-else code should be more along these lines (syntax may not be correct):

```
|gotoIf|${Deletes==true}|Stepssingle|
|else|||
|gotoLabel|Stepsgroup||
|endif|||
```

Alternatively, you could use a more direct if-else structure.

```
|if|${Deletes==true}||
|gotoLabel|Stepsgroup||
|else|||
|gotoLabel|Stepsgroup||
|endif|||
```