# How do I find the word shares that every sentence changes and the word stays

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

```
<span> 50 Line 1 shares $ 22.60 </span>
```

this is what i wrote and get fail

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=#first &gt; span</td>
    <td>shares</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This should have been a new question not an edit of an older one that this question should actually be.  I've flagged both moderator and OP to revert changes and post this as a separate question.

Comment: related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27310/can-a-selenium-ide-test-continue-when-an-assertelementpresent-fails and https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/selenium-ide-i-have-a-problem-every-time-i-run-this-code-it-does-not-refer-corr

Comment: user25686, What is it that you're trying to do, and how do the other two questions you wrote fit in? I'd love to help solve your problem but I need more info. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use "contains" like this:

```
assertElementPresent css=span:contains('shares')
```

Note that 'span' in unlikely to be unique however (there are almost certainly lots of them on the page).  So you will need to look at the surrounding structure to see what tags will be better for isolating these elements.  You could use `span[which_one]` but it would be better to use other markup such as `form#change_shares span:contains('shares')` (actual code will depend on stuff not shown by you) to specifically uniquely isolate the area of page you wish to target

Comment: I have a problem when the word shares is not found is fail the test I want it to pass on

Comment: Would that not be a different test then?

Comment: It's the same test ,I just got stuck with how I find the word but it stumbles my test

Comment: You are supposed to accept my answer and then post that as a separate question.  You should revert the above changes to the question and do that.  Remember this site is a place for the many people with the same problem so it's important to get this right even if you have been helped.  I may ask moderator to revert question change also.

Comment: Ok I וunderstand I open a new question