# Can a Selenium IDE test continue when an assertElementPresent fails?

Tags: selenium, browser-automation, selenium-ide

I'm just a little stuck with the Syntax and how I put up to stepsgroup adds &&          assertElementPresent
            css=span:contains('shares')

How can I edit the script to do this?

```
 <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=web_user_user_id</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=Ok</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Deletes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>while</td>
        <td>${Deletes} == true</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>${Deletes}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gotoIf</td>
        <td>${Deletes}==true</td>
        <td>Stepssingle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>gotoIf</td>
        <td>${Deletes}==false</td>
        <td>Stepsgroup</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>Stepssingle</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>Delete Value: ${Deletes}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Deletes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>End</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>Stepsgroup</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>assertElementPresent</td>
        <td>css=span:contains('shares')</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[2]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>echo</td>
        <td>Delete Value: ${Delete}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeElementPresent</td>
        <td>link=Delete</td>
        <td>Deletes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>End</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>endWhile</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>label</td>
        <td>stepscontinue</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>link=Single</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=bet_order_item_attributes_bulk_id_185</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>id=bet_order_item_attributes_buy_option_bulk_buy</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>css=#bet_68 &gt; div.hide &gt; #bet_order_item_attributes_buy_option_bulk_buy</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>css=#bet_60 &gt; div.hide &gt; #bet_order_item_attributes_buy_option_bulk_buy</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>css=#bet-group &gt; div.hide &gt; #bet_order_item_attributes_buy_option_bulk_buy</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>css=i.fa.fa-arrow-right</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>id=code</td>
        <td>new15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>css=#new_reduction &gt; input[name=&quot;commit&quot;]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>clickAndWait</td>
        <td>link=Clear</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>pause</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>storeEval</td>
        <td>${i} + 1</td>
        <td>i</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>endWhile</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
```

Comment: Hi there. you have asked a few questions about selenium all from a similar perspective. I'm wondering if you need to go to a training site like https://www.lynda.com/Selenium-tutorials/11140-0.html, which give a 10 day free membership. (note I'm not commented with Lynda), then I think you will find answers to these questions yourself

Comment: You need to learn programming. There are plenty of free online courses. We will NOT do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Replace **assertElementPresent** with **verifyElementPresent**.

The difference is basically this (taken from Selenium docs).

> Choosing between “assert” and “verify” comes down to convenience and
>   management of failures. There’s very little point checking that the
>   first paragraph on the page is the correct one if your test has
>   already failed when checking that the browser is displaying the
>   expected page. If you’re not on the correct page, you’ll probably want
>   to abort your test case so that you can investigate the cause and fix
>   the issue(s) promptly. On the other hand, you may want to check many
>   attributes of a page without aborting the test case on the first
>   failure as this will allow you to review all failures on the page and
>   take the appropriate action. **Effectively an “assert” will fail the
>   test and abort the current test case, whereas a “verify” will fail the
>   test and continue to run the test case.**

For making a step optional, you need conditional logic. You'll need javascript and/or Selenium extensions, refer to [the answers in this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995718/is-there-a-way-to-make-actions-optional-in-selenium-ide).

Comment: I tried to change to verifyElementPresent, but it still check me for the stepsgroup. The test is that once the word "shares" does not appear I do not want it to perform the stepsgroup test. Follow I'm stuck and breaking my head

Comment: You need to put it in an if statement so the verify check will trigger which way it goes on steps.

Comment: @user25686 edited answer with a link that might help you out, I think